# Add class to the next element with specific class in different div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create **jquery** function which will add class `"active"` to the next element with specific class on button click.

HTML:

```
<button class="next">next</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"><p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected1</p>
        <p class="textcontent">content1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
    <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"><p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected2</p>
        <p class="textcontent">content2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
    <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"><p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected3</p>
        <p class="textcontent">content3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("p.ToBeSelected").first().addClass("active");

$("button.next").click(function () {
    $("p.ToBeSelected.active").removeClass("active");
  $("p.ToBeSelected").addClass("active");
}
);
```

When the button is **clicked** all elements with class `"ToBeSelected"` are given the `"active"` class.
Instead of that, only next element with class `"ToBeSelected"` should be getting the `"active"` class.
So I've tried that:

```
$("p.ToBeSelected").first().addClass("active");

$("button.next").click(function () {
    $("p.ToBeSelected.active").removeClass("active");
  $("p.ToBeSelected").next().addClass("active");
}
);
```

But it doesn't work either.
It probably can be done in many different ways and I've tried many but none of them are working as I would want to. Also, I have no trouble with getting it work when there are no elements separating the elements with `"ToBeSelected"` class.
I hope I could get help from you guys!

```js
$("p.ToBeSelected").first().addClass("active");

$("button.next").click(function() {
  $("p.ToBeSelected.active").removeClass("active");
  $("p.ToBeSelected").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">next</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected1</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected2</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected3</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store two variables:

- `i`: the zero-based index of the selected item;
- `n`: the number of selectable items.

Then, when the user clicks on the `.next` button, you should:

- remove the `active` class from every (selected) item;
- increase `i`, using the modulo operation (`%`) if you want to start from the beginning;
- add the `active` class to the `i`-th item.

```js
$(function() {
  let i = 0;
  let n = $("p.ToBeSelected").length;
  $("p.ToBeSelected:eq(" + i + ")").addClass("active");
  $("button.next").click(function() {
    $("p.ToBeSelected.active").removeClass("active");
    i = (i + 1) % n;
    $("p.ToBeSelected:eq(" + i + ")").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">next</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected1</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected2</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <p>blahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="ToBeSelected">ToBeSelected3</p>
    <p class="textcontent">content3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. That's a cool apporach to make it work, definitely learned something new. Thanks a lot!